# How to remove currently selected date from Keith Wood's Datepick

Tags: jquery

I'm using Keith Wood's Datepick http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html, and i want to remove currently selected date from my input field. How can i achieve it?

i am using following code-

```
function onload(){
$jQ("#"+id).datepick({
           dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
           onShow: function() {maxValueLimit(countId);}
       });
}

function maxValueLimit(id){
        var maxValuesPerKeyPerNetwork = 20;
        var uiValueArr= new Array();
        var dates = $jQ("#datePicker_" + counterId).datepick('getDate');

        for (var ii = 0; ii < dates.length; ii++) {

            uiValueArr[uiValueArr.length] = $jQ.datepick.formatDate(dates[ii]);;
        }

       if(uiValueArr.length > maxValuesPerKeyPerNetwork){
            alert("You have already reached the limit of values assigned to this key.");        
        }
}
```

- I have added 2 dates i.e.09/01/2013,09/02/2013 & now want to add one more i.e. 09/03/2013 but while adding this i want to show alert to user that "you have reached limit".
- At the same time i want to remove that currently selected date (i.e.09/03/2013 ) .
- I have attached my screen shot.

Comment: Please give examples of your code what you have tried so far. :-)

Comment: I read documentation of it but still i didn't get anything to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think remove insense, empty value right.  Then try this

```
$('.datepicker').val('');
```

Comment: There are many dates in my input field & I want to remove only latest selected date.